# Issue with username regex validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I searched SO before posting, but couldn't find an answer that would work for me.

Below is a **simple JS script to test a username.**

The username length validation work fine BUT **the character validation** doesn't:

All non-allowed characters (such as $%;[+)) pass whereas they should return an error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#username").change(function() {
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var msgbox = $("#status");
        var usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]$i/

         if ((username.length >= 4 && username.length <= 20) &&  
 (usernameRegex.test(username.value) == false)) {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "username.php",
                data: "username=" + username,
                success: function(msg) {

                    if (msg == 'OK') {

                        msgbox.html('<img src="ok.png">');

                    } else {
                        msgbox.html(msg);
                    }
                }
             });
        } else {

            $("#status").html('<img src="no.png">Try again');
        }
     });
});
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: username = $("#username").val()
then again in the statement username.value
I think you are putting the wrong thing in your if statement

Comment: Shouldn't `usernameRegex.test(username.value) == false` be `usernameRegex.test(username.value) == true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a problem with your regular expression, and it's not just the `$i/`. You have:

```
var usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]$i/;
```

That second token, `[a-zA-Z0-9\._-]`, is only evaluated once. It checks the first character for the first token, then the second character for the second token, and then *expects the end of the string* because of `$`. Even after changing your test condition to `true` and fixing the rest of the logic, your original regular expression will **fail all usernames above two characters.**

Try this instead:

```
var usernameRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]+$/i;
```

The `+` ensures that the regex will look for **at least one** character in the token, and match them until the string ends.

Finally, as others have mentioned, you need `usernameRegex.test(username)` instead of `usernameRegex.test(username.value)`, and it needs to test for a `true` value, not `false`.

### [**See a working demo here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/4Kk4Z/)

Comment: Thanks ! Indeed, there was something wrong with the regex too !

Answer (score 1):

You are examining the results of your test backwards.  The `test()` method returns `true` if the pattern matches.  And you are checking for a false value.

Change it to:

```
if ((username.length >= 4 && username.length <= 20) 
    &&  usernameRegex.test(username.value)) {
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FRegExp%2Ftest

Answer (score 1):

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]{4,20}$i/
                                  ^^
                        Here is the problem
```

You probably wanted to specify the case-insensitive flag but by accident you put `i` inside the regular expression pattern itself, you need to modify your expression to this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\._-]{4,20}$/i
```

and as they guys have pointed out you should test for a `true` condition or in other words, you need to check if the string actually matches the pattern and thus contains only the characters you allow.